# Android Studio, Maven does not use Android SDK repository

Tags: android, maven, android-studio

I'm working on a Maven project that imports the Google Play Services. Except it can't.

I've installed Android Studio with the SDK, and had it download both the Android and the Google Maven repositories (they are in the extras/[google/android]/m2repository folders). Android Studio and the project uses the proper Android SDK, and every other setting seems to be fine, except Maven cannot find these two repositories.

How can one solve such an issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add these repositories in your POM file, like this:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>android-support</id>
        <url>file://${env.ANDROID_HOME}/extras/android/m2repository</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work - the repo was added and recognized, but the files did not load.

Is it possible that it fails because Google changed version numbering, and my project references version 19.0.0 (API version instead of release version e.g. 6.5.87), types apklib and jar

Comment: yeah, i guess thats the reason. why not try using the release version? you can find all available versions in "android-sdk-/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services"

Comment: By release version I meant it has the version numbers of the available packages are not of the Android API (for what this project looks for, e.g. 19.0.1), but apparently a separate version format (6.5.87, 5.0.1, 4.4.59, etc.).